# How to write generic code while avoiding indirect calls?

Tags: c#, .net, optimization, virtual-functions

Is there any way to call write generic programs and algorithms in C# while **avoiding** the overhead of a dynamic solution?

Consider a simple example:

```
static void QuickSort<T>(T[] arr, int left, int right, Comparison<T> compare)
{
    do
    {
        int i = left;
        int j = right;
        var x = arr[i + ((j - i) >> 1)];
        do
        {
            while (i < arr.Length && compare(x, arr[i]) > 0) i++;
            while (j >= 0 && compare(x, arr[j]) < 0) j--;
            if (i > j) { break; }
            if (i < j)
            {
                var temp = arr[i];
                arr[i] = arr[j];
                arr[j] = temp;
            }
            i++;
            j--;
        } while (i <= j);
        if (j - left <= right - i)
        {
            if (left < j) QuickSort(arr, left, j, compare);
            left = i;
        }
        else
        {
            if (i < right) QuickSort(arr, i, right, compare);
            right = j;
        }
    } while (left < right);
}
```

Which you might call as:

```
QuickSort(buffer, 0, buffer.Length - 1, (a, b) => a.CompareTo(b))
```

While seemingly efficient, this benign-looking example *performs an **indirect** (i.e. virtual) call* for *every* comparison.

Obviously, the processor cannot optimize indirect calls, and therefore they perform poorly. On my computer, this translates into a 25% decrease in performance, from about 3,600 items/ms to 2,700 items/ms.

Is there any way to avoid such indirect calls in writing generic code?
No matter how much juggling I do with delegates, `DynamicMethod`, and the like, it seems like there is *always* an indirect call between the library code and the user's code, which obviously impacts performance very negatively.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Actually, I finally realized that the solution is dead simple:

### Use generics + interfaces instead of delegates!

Example:

```
static void QuickSort<TCmp, T>(T[] arr, int left, int right, TCmp cmp)
    where TCmp : IComparer<T>
{
    do
    {
        int i = left;
        int j = right;
        var x = arr[i + ((j - i) >> 1)];
        do
        {
            while (i < arr.Length && cmp.Compare(x, arr[i]) > 0) i++;
            while (j >= 0 && cmp.Compare(x, arr[j]) < 0) j--;
            if (i > j) { break; }
            if (i < j)
            {
                var temp = arr[i];
                arr[i] = arr[j];
                arr[j] = temp;
            }
        } while (++i <= --j);
        if (j - left <= right - i)
        {
            if (left < j) QuickSort<TCmp, T>(arr, left, j, cmp);
            left = i;
        }
        else
        {
            if (i < right) QuickSort<TCmp, T>(arr, i, right, cmp);
            right = j;
        }
    } while (left < right);
}
```

On my computer, when I compare the old version using

```
QuickSort(copy1, 0, copy1.Length - 1, (x, y) => x.CompareTo(y));
```

with the new version that uses

```
QuickSort(copy1, 0, copy1.Length - 1, comparer);
```

I get a nice  (~30%) gain in speed.

Comment: Does it make a difference if you use just `static void QuickSort<T>(T[] arr, int left, int right, IComparer<T> cmp)` (assuming the comparer is a `class`, not a `struct`)?

Comment: @svick: You should try it and see; I think it *should*, but I don't have it in front of me right now to test.

Answer (score 5):

In case of comparing items the answer is no: you cannot put, say, a `>` between `x` and `arr[j]`, and expect the compiler to figure out that you meant it to apply its built-in `>` operator on objects of type `T`.

However, your solution could be optimized a little, because you are paying for the indirection twice. Since you have declared your `T` an `IComparable<T>` already, you could drop the `comparator` parameter, and call `x.CompareTo(arr[j])` without going through the lambda. This would cutting down on the overhead of a second indirection. Of course it would not let you customize the way in which you compare your items, but that would be a routine case of paying for flexibility with CPU cycles.

Comment: But that only works in the (very) special case that the built-in comparator is sufficient. But if you're sorting by a different key (say, a person's age instead of his social security number), then you have to use `IComparer<T>` -- there is no other way. So it's just a solution tailored to this specific example, not something that you can use generally

Comment: @Mehrdad This is precisely what the last sentence of my answer is about: if you need flexibility (in your case, a way to supply a comparator at run time) you pay with CPU cycles (in your case, an invocation of a virtual function).

Answer (score 2):

Your results are going to depend very much on the type of `T` and on how expensive the comparisons are.

I created custom versions of your `QuickSort` methods: one that expects an array of `int`, and one that expects an array of `string`. The modifications are limited to removing the comparison parameter and changing the two comparisons in the partitioner. I modified them to sort in reverse, like this:

```
while (i < arr.Length && arr[i].CompareTo(x) > 0) i++;
while (j >= 0 && arr[j].CompareTo(x) < 0) j--;
```

I then tested those methods against your generic method, using arrays of 10 million items. My results:

```
Int: Generic QuickSort - 2,190 ms
Int: Custom QuickSort - 1,252 ms
String: Generic QuickSort - 32,902 ms
String: Custom QuickSort - 31,634 ms
```

My conclusion is that if comparison is very inexpensive (as it is with `int` and other native types), then you are going to notice a big difference in performance. If comparison is expensive (strings are pretty expensive to compare), that virtual call overhead is lost in the cost of the comparison.

I know that doesn't provide a solution to your problem; I don't think there is one. Flexibility often comes at a cost.

The people who built the base class libraries understood that. For example, they created special cases for primitive types that use the default `IComparer`. Compare the difference in running time when calling `Array.Sort` in these two ways (using an `int[10000000]`):

```
Array.Sort(a);  // 845 ms
Array.Sort(a, (a, b) => a.CompareTo(b)); // 2,339 ms
```

It turns out that `Array.Sort` has built-in optimizations for primitive types that use their default `IComparer`. See [Of Comparison and IComparer](http://www.informit.com/guides/content.aspx?g=dotnet&seqNum=781) for a little more info about that.

Answer (score 1):

I think that dasblinkenlight is right, but I'd venture to guess as to why:

When you pass a Comparer to the QuickSort method the Framework is creating a generic implementation of the `System.Comparison` delegate (`System.Comparison`1` for example).  Calls to any generic delegates are virtual, which makes sense- how would the compiler be able to statically generate a call to a method on a generic type that is only created at run-time?

Reed Copsey describes this in more depth here: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/csharplanguage/thread/b94c7506-e21f-43b1-be9a-bf88f8f72f36

The closest that I could get was a factory pattern that returns a non-virtual call for known types:

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            const int size = 50000;
            var ra = RandomArray(size);
            var buffer = Enumerable.Range(0, size).OrderBy(i => ra[i]).ToArray();
            Debug.WriteLine(String.Join(",", buffer));
            new IntSorter().QuickSort(buffer);
            Debug.WriteLine(String.Join(",", buffer));

        }

        public IQuickSorter<T> GetSorter<T>() where T : IComparable<T>
        {
            if (typeof(T).Equals(typeof(Int32)))
                return (IQuickSorter<T>) new IntSorter();
            return new GenericSorter<T>();
        }

        public static Int32[] RandomArray(Int32 length)
        {
            var r = new Random();
            return Enumerable.Range(0, length).Select(i => r.Next(0, length + 1)).ToArray();
        }
    }

    public class IntSorter : IQuickSorter<int>
    {
        public void QuickSort(int[] arr)
        {
            QuickSortInner(arr, 0, arr.Length-1);
        }

        public void QuickSortInner(int[] arr, int left, int right)
        {
            do
            {
                int i = left;
                int j = right;
                var x = arr[i + ((j - i) >> 1)];
                do
                {
                    while (i < arr.Length && x.CompareTo(arr[i]) > 0) i++;
                    while (j >= 0 && x.CompareTo(arr[j]) < 0) j--;
                    if (i > j)
                    {
                        break;
                    }
                    if (i < j)
                    {
                        var temp = arr[i];
                        arr[i] = arr[j];
                        arr[j] = temp;
                    }
                    i++;
                    j--;
                } while (i <= j);
                if (j - left <= right - i)
                {
                    if (left < j) QuickSortInner(arr, left, j);
                    left = i;
                }
                else
                {
                    if (i < right) QuickSortInner(arr, i, right);
                    right = j;
                }
            } while (left < right);
        }
    }

    public class GenericSorter<T> : IQuickSorter<T> where T : IComparable<T>
    {
        public void QuickSort(T[] arr)
        {
            QuickSortInner(arr, 0, arr.Length - 1);
        }

        public void QuickSortInner(T[] arr, int left, int right)
        {
            do
            {
                int i = left;
                int j = right;
                var x = arr[i + ((j - i) >> 1)];
                do
                {
                    while (i < arr.Length && x.CompareTo(arr[i]) > 0) i++;
                    while (j >= 0 && x.CompareTo(arr[j]) < 0) j--;
                    if (i > j) { break; }
                    if (i < j)
                    {
                        var temp = arr[i];
                        arr[i] = arr[j];
                        arr[j] = temp;
                    }
                    i++;
                    j--;
                } while (i <= j);
                if (j - left <= right - i)
                {
                    if (left < j) QuickSortInner(arr, left, j);
                    left = i;
                }
                else
                {
                    if (i < right) QuickSortInner(arr, i, right);
                    right = j;
                }
            } while (left < right);
        }
    }

    public interface IQuickSorter<in T>
    {
        void QuickSort(T[] arr);
    }
}
```

Comment: But that only works in the (very) special case that the built-in comparator is sufficient. But if you're sorting by a different key (say, a person's age instead of his social security number), then you have to use `IComparer<T>` -- there is no other way. So it's just a solution tailored to this specific example, not something that you can use generally.

Comment: Well, you could plug in any arbitrary concrete sorter to the factory method. But you need to do that in advance, yes, so it isn't perfectly generic.

Comment: Sorry, I guess I wasn't clear.... the problem here is that you're assuming `where T : IComparable<T>` actually holds. For many data real-world types, it never does. So unless you expect the user to copy-paste the entire source code for your method just to change a single method call (which is a pretty bad idea, for obvious reasons), I'm confused at how this would actually work.

Comment: I do expect them to copy/paste. As I explain above, there is no way for it to work otherwise.

Comment: I hope it's obvious why that's not useful/practical. :\

Comment: As dasblinkenlight mentioned, it's a flexibility/performance tradeoff. My example just shows how you can provide a "fast special case".

Answer (score 0):

Put the quicksort method in an abstract type and get rid of the use of the delegate completely.

First, create the abstract type.  Note the new abstract 'compare' method, and the lack of the delegate on the QuickSort method:

```
public abstract class QuickSort<T>
{
    protected static abstract int compare(T x, T y);

    public static void QuickSort(T[] arr, int left, int right)
    {
        do
        {
            int i = left;
            int j = right;
            var x = arr[i + ((j - i) >> 1)];
            do
            {
                while (i  0) i++;
                while (j >= 0 && compare(x, arr[j]) < 0) j--;
                if (i > j) { break; }
                if (i < j)
                {
                    var temp = arr[i];
                    arr[i] = arr[j];
                    arr[j] = temp;
                }
                i++;
                j--;
            } while (i <= j);
            if (j - left <= right - i)
            {
                if (left < j) QuickSort(arr, left, j);
                left = i;
            }
            else
            {
                if (i < right) QuickSort(arr, i, right);
                right = j;
            }
        } while (left < right);
    }
}
```

Next, create a class that inherits from QuickSort and implements the compare method.  We'll use ints for our example:

```
public class QuickSortInt : QuickSort<int>
{
    protected static override int compare(int x, int y)
    {
        if (x < y) return -1;
        if (x > y) return 1;
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: This doesn't compile...  You can't have an abstract static method.  If you make it an instance method, it results in a `callvirt` also.

Comment: D'oh.  I seem to have a hard time getting it into my head that static and abstract methods don't mix.